# Django views.py function

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run an enternal python script upon clicking a button in a django website, however I think the path of my external script which i have specified is in the wrong formatting:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from subprocess import run,PIPE
import requests
import sys
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

@csrf_exempt
def external(request):
    inp=request.POST.get('param')
    out=run(sys.executable==['//D://Desktop//new//file1//test.py',inp], shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    print(out)
    return render(requests, "index.html",{'data1':out})
```

I also have an error which says

```
TypeError at /external/
'bool' object is not iterable
```

when I run it on the local server.

My urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views as v
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', v.index, name="index"),
    path("external/",  v.external),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: What is `sys.executable==['//D://Desktop//new//file1//test.py',inp]` supposed t do?

Comment: Note that there is a double = sign here `out=run(sys.executable==['//D://Desktop//new//file1//test.py',inp], shell=False,stdout=PIPE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, you wrote:

```
out=run(sys.executable==['//D://Desktop//new//file1//test.py',inp], shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
```

But that makes not much sense: you are here comparing `sys.executable` (which is a string), with a list of strings, and therefore it will return `False`. So you then call `run(False, shell=False, stdout=PIPE)`, but `False` is of course not a string.

You can rewrite this to:

```
out=run([sys.executable, '//D://Desktop//new//file1//test.py',inp], shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
```